# Gmail push notifications in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, push-notification, classification, gmail-imap

I am developing an application where users add their Gmail accounts, and I do some classification work on their emails.

I want to be notified when a new email comes to any of the registered accounts.

A solution is to keep polling the accounts via IMAP and saving the last email date I have fetched to check whether there is a new mail or not, but this has a lot of overhead.

Any idea how to monitor Gmail and be notified when a new email is received and integrate this with a Rails app? Is there an extension which can do that and send a post request to my Rails application for example?

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040344/how-to-receive-push-notification-from-my-gmail-account

Comment: yes , but the other question did not reach a solution too

Comment: I think @Shakes is seeking a Rails-specific tool for Gmail push notifications, so this question is significantly different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040344/how-to-receive-push-notification-from-my-gmail-account

Comment: @Shakes To answer this style of question ("are there gems for X?"), it is very useful to search http://rubygems.org and http://ruby-toolbox.com. My answer below involved searching for "IMAP" and "Gmail" and weeding out some old, inactive projects.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure IMAP is the only answer here.

You may want to see whether IDLE works--I've read conflicting answers. If it does, it's way more responsive than polling.

Otherwise, poll away.

[Wikipedia article on IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP_IDLE)

Comment: is there any ruby implementation for imap idle ? i saw conflicting answers for net/imap too. it would be great if there is a gem which implements this feature

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

1. If you want low-level, Ruby provides [Net::IMAP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/Net/IMAP.html).
2. You can try the [imap_processor](http://rubygems.org/gems/imap_processor) gem.
3. You can try the [gmail](http://rubygems.org/gems/gmail) gem.

Dig into them and let us know what works for you, particularly with regards to IDLE.